# How to convert number string in an array to number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to use Fisher Yates shuffle algorithm to shuffle each integer from `Math.random()`after the ". (dot)". I split them into string and use the Fisher Yates shuffle algorithm but I am stuck on how to convert it back to number.

**From:** ["0", ".", "4", "1", "2", "7", "2", "9", "5", "8", "6", "7", "0", "7", "4", "2", "8", "1"]

**To:** 0.4127295867074281

```
    var randomNum = Math.random();
    var stringNum = randomNum.toString();
    var stringArray = stringNum.split("");

    var i = stringArray;
    var j;
    var temp;

    while (--i > 1) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        temp = stringArray[j];
        stringArray[j] = stringArray[i];
        stringArray[i] = temp;
    }
```

Comment: If you can't trust your RNG to give you a random number, how can you trust your RNG to shuffle your random number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First join the array and then cast to number `Number(strArray.join(""))`

```js
var strArray = ["0", ".", "4", "1", "2", "7", "2", "9", "5", "8", "6", "7", "0", "7", "4", "2", "8", "1"];

var num = Number(strArray.join(""));

// this prints 0.4127295867074281
document.write(num);
```

Comment: Glad that it helped :)

Comment: You can also use `String(randomNum)` instead of `randomNum.toString();`

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = "42";
var num = str * 1;
```

For the full number:

```
var fullNum = stringArray.join("") * 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm amazing with logic, but not so much with each language but here is a basic, idea in logic. Remember below I am concatenating

x = 0
y = 0

while( y > 10)

z = generate random number greater that 0 and less than 10;

x = "x" + "." + "z"

end

answer = x

answer = answer + x